# Apple programming guide for iOS background execution guide example?

Tags: ios, race-condition, uibackgroundtask

So on this page there is an example about background execution: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1, here is the example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{

        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });

}
```

It is said that `bgTask` is defined in class as variable. So there is one `bgTask` property for every instance of class (object). If `applicationDidEnterBackground` were to be called multiple times before async block finishes, isn't here danger of race condition? I mean `bgTask` would change its value, and `endBackgroundTask` would be called on new task value, instead of old value?

Isn't here a better solution to do this:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
```

before calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`?

Comment: you should check if bgTask is not invalid and end it before assigning to it new value.

Comment: if ( _bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid )
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
    
    WEAK_SELF weakSelf = self;
    _bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:weakSelf.bgTask];
        weakSelf.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one instance of of `bgTask` for each object, but this is on the `AppDelegate`, not some general VC or object. So there will technically only ever be one `bgTask` instance at work.

But this still creates problems. Since if this method gets called twice it will override `bgTask`'s value. My first thought was that upon exiting the app, more than once, all previous tasks would expire. But after testing realized this was not the case (which is a good thing IMO). What did happen is that `bgTask` was overwritten (as expected) and the new value was passed to the first `endBackgroundTask:` call. Immediate afterward `bgTask` is set to `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` which clears it out and the cleared value is passed to any subsequent calls to `endBackgroundTask:`. This obviously resulted in an unclean termination since not all the unique id's would have been ended, leading to the `expiration` handler executing on any left over background tasks.

That being said, I believe your assumption about using a local variable is correct. If you try out this code (placed in the `AppDelegate` `applicationDidEnterBackground:`):

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    NSLog(@"Expired");
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

NSLog(@"Backgrounded: %@", @(bgTask));

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Done! %@", @(bgTask));
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
});
```

You will see that each local `bgTask` is assigned a unique value and properly completed after 10 seconds (as per the `dispatch_after` call).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you address is the following:
An app is sent to the `Background` state, and iOS calls `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.
A background task is started, which may take up to a few minutes.
During this time, the app is activated again, and sent to background again, which calls again `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, and starts another background task, whereby variable `bgTask` would be overwritten, if it is not a block variable.  This is correct. Thus, `bgTask` should indeed be a block variable.
Related to this problem is the question, how you could finish the background execution, if multiple background tasks have been started. An example, how you can do this, is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659410/using-multiple-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler-calls).
The idea is to have a variable that counts the active background tasks. As soon as all of them are finished, one can terminate the background execution.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, when called for the second time, `applicationDidEnterBackground` will cause problems. But in order for the method to be called a second time, the application first needs be put into the foreground again. So the solution is easy. Simply call your expiration handler from `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

```
- (void)expireBackgroundTask {
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];            
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        [self expireBackgroundTask];
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self expireBackgroundTask];
}
```