# Implementing a way to upload data to a server when the app is terminated/ i background in Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating this app which uploads some data to a server. User can change data offline and app can upload this data when phone comes online. But this upload process must be able to accomplish even the app is closed. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find limitations in your way. Although iOS enables you to define specific "background modes" for apps that incorporate voip or location services, normally, when an iOS app is terminated, it means really terminated, unless you keep it open but minimized or unless you ask for additional time for the app to stop running once you terminate it:

[Best practice to send a lot of data in background on iOS4 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928861/best-practice-to-send-a-lot-of-data-in-background-on-ios4-device)

But in the best case, you can't simply keep the app running when it is not running.

Comment: ya you are right. As my app don't fall in any of the background modes, I can't run the app in background or suspension state. Have to abandon that feature.

Comment: @AsankaIndrajith    can u please help me how you had done this task i m also getting problem to achgieve same task

Comment: Actually you can't achieve that unless your app belongs to one of the categories that apple provide multitasking abilities. Also there isn't a plugin for phonegap-iOS to do it. but Phonegap-Android has a plugin.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService/2.0.0