# DropBox file download operation is not working on Background state with Passcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

If I put download then suddenly **I Lock the Iphone with Passcode**, The downloading progress is getting stopped with in a fraction of seconds. the Dropbox service is not continuing to downloading the progress.

Here this method is for download operation.

```
-(void)downloadFile:(DBMetadata*)file
    {
        if (!file.isDirectory)
        {
           NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

           localPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file.filename];
           [[self restClientForDownload] loadFile:file.path intoPath:localPath];

        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app, running http requests while application in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291840/iphone-app-running-http-requests-while-application-in-background)

Comment: @Abizern. You link is getting "Page not found."

Answer (score -1):

you have to call rest client methods from Main thread. If you're starting the connection from the the main thread, just use GCD to create and start the connection on the main thread -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
NSURLConnection *downManager = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[downManager start];
});
```